# Google Analytics shows 1000s of views coming in from google for a page, but search console showing barely any views for it

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

First time I have seen something like this, anyone have any idea what is going on? For October, analytics showing that the page got 1000 views from google...search console showing like 5 clicks for the entire month.  Quite confused.  Thanks
[image]

[image]